# Obter ultimo valor coluna Access

Tags: vb.net, vba, microsoft-access

Estou a desenvolver uma pequena aplicação que insere dados para uma base dados em access. Estou a conseguir inserir os dados no entanto queria obter o ultimo valor do ID inserido (numero automático) para uma msgbox.

```
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    datafile = "C:\Users\RR\Documents\Database2.mdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "Insert into Guias([Remetente],[Destinatário]) Values (?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Remetente", CType(ComboBox1.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Destinatário", CType(ComboBox2.Text, String)))
```

Comment: Somente para corrigir as Tags, a programação é em VBA ou VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Para saber qual foi o último número inserido utilize a `SQL` `SELECT @@IDENTITY` e no seu código fica assim, ***exemplo***:

```
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
datafile = "C:\Users\RR\Documents\Database2.mdb"
connString = provider & datafile
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()
Dim str As String
str = "Insert into Guias([Remetente],[Destinatário]) Values (?,?)"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Remetente", CType(ComboBox1.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Destinatário", CType(ComboBox2.Text, String)))

//adicioando essas linhas
Dim result As Integer = 0
If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) Then
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
    result = Integer.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
End If
Console.WriteLine("Id inserido:" & result) // a variavel result tem o valor do id inserido
```

***Nota:*** no caso cada `SQL` tem que ser executada separadamente, mas, utilize o mesmo `SQLCommand` só mudando o valor do `CommandText`.

<sub>***Referencia:*** [MS-Access com ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc580610.aspx)</sub>